# php setting encoding iso-8859-1 by default in browser

Tags: php, encoding

I have a php file which when displays data shows strange characters, but when I change encoding from tools in chrome to iso-8859-1 the strange characters are displayed correctly, the strange characters are actually Portuguese alphabets. please tell how can we set by default the encoding to iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

You should ideally use `utf-8`. If it doesn't work automatically, that means it's improperly encoded on the database and you should convert it to utf-8.

Comment: Even though both are not state of the art nowadays, I would recommend to always use `iso-8859-15` if `utf-8` is not an option, as `iso-8859-1` does not include the `€` symbol.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 if someone hits this page it's due to legacy IBM DB2 databases, and good luck convincing the IBM i (AS/400) sysadmin to switch if they haven't already...  It was true at the time of this question, and is still true today.